# Something to encourage? Photos/followup to questions.

Tags: discussion

There are so many great questions on this board, and it seems one thing that can be done to both increase the sense of community, and make answering/asking questions more rewarding, is to encourage people to show the results of an answered question.  I took the opportunity to do so here:

Original question:
[What are the best practices for a low deck built half on a concrete slab?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/2247/low-deck-half-on-slab)

Response with picture of the resulting deck:
[What are the best practices for a low deck built half on a concrete slab?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/2247/low-deck-half-on-slab/2788#2788)

Thoughts?  Is this a precedent that is worth setting?  If so, what is the most appropriate way to do this?  An answer to your own question (I like this, because it bumps the question to the top of the active list, as a reminder)?  As an edit to the original question?

Comment: I'd add it as an edit to the original question, clearly indicating that it's an update.

Comment: I agree with Doresoom.  I DEFINITELY like the picture but think an update to the original question would be more appropriate.

Comment: Does anyone know if an update to the original question bumps (or can be set to bump) the question to the top of the "questions" list?  My only concern is that one might finish a project days, weeks, or (in my case) even a month or more after asking a question.  Posting an update to a question that old, if it isn't bumped, will basically go unseen.

Comment: It bumps to the top of the "active" tab, much like I think an answer does.  I don't believe any other tabs are reordered based on new edit or answer.

Comment: @Steve Jackson- Good to know Steve!

Answer (score 7):

I like the idea!  I gave it a try as an edit to the original question:
[Why am I finding condensation in my dryer?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1171/condensation-in-dryer)

Answer (score 5):

It might be more appropriate to post it as an answer - after all it's your solution to the problem.

It would keep the problem and solution separate.

Comment: You're swaying my vote...It also helps with comments - is a comment about the original question or the followup?

Comment: Perhaps it depends on the type of solution that is posted.  If it is simply taking one of the suggestions, and using it for the fix, then tacking it on to the original question works.  On the other hand, if coming up with something slightly different, or showing specifics on how the problem was solved, it would merit its own answer... thoughts?

Comment: @MarkD I agree with you.  If the end solution is different from the other proposed answers, then it should be listed as an answer.  However if it's exactly the same as the other proposed answers, then I think it should be in comments so that due credit is given to the original poster.

Answer (score 0):

Something to encourage, I suppose, but not really that big of a deal.  You can definitely do it -- it's easy to add it to the original question or as an answer, and you will most likely get upvoted for it quite a bit as a result.  The ability to add it is already in place, and the reward for doing so is as well.

That said, if they really wanted to, they could definitely add some new functionality with which you could post your result/finished project/etc.  Perhaps a "spoiler" button or a section down at the bottom of the page that has a special banner across the top that read "Follow-Up", "Finished Result", or whatever.

If they wanted to take it one step further, they could maybe even allow people to post how-to's, showing not only the initial problem/question and final solution, etc., but all of the steps in between.

Answer (score 0):

It is such a reward to the people who helped, to see how it all turned out.  We need both a convention for this and an carrot/stick.  How about negative points if you don't even bother to read an answer posted in the first few days?