# Would it be in bad taste to post a picture of a completed result of a question I posted?

Tags: discussion, questions

With the help I received in my question [how do I fix an uneven cement floor prior to hardwood flooring install](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/16949/how-do-i-fix-an-uneven-cement-floor-prior-to-hard-wood-flooring-install), the process of install was great. I would like to share with the answer posters the results of their help. Would this be unwanted here?

Comment: Related: http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/questions/206/something-to-encourage-photos-followup-to-questions

Comment: Sweet! TY Niall C

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why would it be in bad taste?  It's another way of giving positive feedback -- beyond commenting, upvoting and accepting -- to the people who helped you with the problem you were having.

In the related question, [Something to encourage? Photos/followup to questions.](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/206/something-to-encourage-photos-followup-to-questions), they talk about doing it either as an update to the question, or posting a separate answer.  However, since that question was posted, the [DIY blog](http://diy.blogoverflow.com/?blb=1) has gone live, so a third way of sharing your work is to write a blog post.  If you're interested, drop into the [DIY chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111/home-improvement), say the word "blog", and prepare to be mobbed (in a good way) as you get set up to write one.

Comment: I'll second writing it up as a blog post. It doesn't have to have many words. Just something along the lines of "Thanks to the answers on [this question](link) I was able to do this:" :)