# Adding answer to my own question with details on how I resolved it?

Tags: discussion, answers

A couple of weeks ago I asked [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/133122) on how to fix a cracked stair step. I got a good answer, and have acted on it. During the process I learned more that might be helpful to future searchers:

- results of cutting into the ceiling below the cracked step
- what I used as a reinforcing board
- how to "clamp" the reinforcing board against the underside of the step
- notes on appearance of eventual patch to under-stairway ceiling
- other experiences (e.g. the crack widened)

Would it be appropriate to post an answer to my own question, giving the process with pictures? I'm fine with leaving the existing answer (which gave me good information) checked as the correct one.

Comment: https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/686/would-it-be-in-bad-taste-to-post-a-picture-of-a-completed-result-of-a-question-i

Answer (score 2):

Self answers are encouraged on SE when they answer the question without duplicating an existing answer. Other forms of follow up that the community frequently appreciates:

- For a results photo, many will edit the question with a picture and credit to the below answer that helped them get that result.
- Comments are frequently used for a brief update on details that an existing answer didn't cover.

Competing answers on SE are welcome when you have more than would be covered by the above. As you've noted, giving thanks in the form of credit, votes, and accepted answer to someone else that provided the most help in solving your problem is appreciated and a common courtesy.